# Placing simple char markers in a board of array for a simple candy crush game

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am a first year degree student in ICT and my assignment requires me to develop a simple candy crush game.

So my issue right now is to print the markers( i.e `"|"` and `"_"` ) that surrounds the number at `board[5][5]` when the program initialize.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//FUNCTION: Draw the Board
int drawBoard()
{
    //Declare array size
    int board[9][9];

    //initialize variables
    int rows, columns, randomNumber, flag;

    //random number seed generator
    srand(time(NULL));

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
            {
                flag = 0;

                do
               {
                    //generate random numbers from 2 - 8
                randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;

                board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;

                //Checks for 2 adjacent numbers.
                if  ( board[rows][columns] == board[rows - 1][columns] || board[rows][columns] == board[rows][columns - 1] )
                    {
                        flag = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                else
                     {
                        flag = 1;
                        printf( "  %d  ", board[rows][columns] );
                     }

                } while ( flag == 0 );

            }//end inner for-loop

            printf("\n\n");
        }//end outer for-loop

marker();
}//end FUNCTION drawBoard

//FUNCTION: Mark the surrounding of the number with "|" and "_" at board[5][5]
void marker()
{
    printf( " _ \n" );
    printf( "|%c|\n", a );
    printf( " _ \n" );   
}

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
}
```

So...yeah I'm stuck at this part:

```
printf( "%c" , drawBoard(board[5][5]) );
printf( "\n\n%c" , drawBoard( board[5][5]) );
```

Well I guess I am just weak at function. I want to create a separate function( `i.e void marker()` ) that can be called in the `drawBoard` function, and then have function `marker()` to mark the surrounding area of the number at coordinate `board[5][5]`.

Am I thinking and doing it in a wrong way? Please advice.

Sam

EDIT 1: Thanks for the help haccks! Yeah I think I understand the basic usage of function now. The remaining problem is that even though I called `marker( board[5][5] )` from `drawBoard()`, the printing of the marker **does not happen** on the number that is placed in board[5][5].

The marker is printed after the board is printed. Any idea why this happens? By right it should be printed at the coordinate [5][5] :/

Comment: Please read SO [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) note.

Comment: Hi haccks, I just read it :) Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 0):

Your `marker` function is wrong. You are using `board[5][5]` in this function (which is declared in `drawBoard`) without passing to it.
You can do this as
     marker(board[5][5]); // call from drawBoard()

```
  void marker(int a)
  {
      printf( " _ \n");
      printf( "|%c|\n" , a );
      printf( " _ \n");
  }
```